# GAC Oracle.DataAccess DLL Error While Installing ClickOnce Application

Tags: c#, oracle, deployment, clickonce, gac

I am getting following error while installing the Click-Once Application on my machine.

Error says...

> *<< Title of Message Box >>*
>
> **System Update Required**
>
> *<< Message Details >>*
>
> **Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly Oracle.DataAccess Version 2.112.1.0 be installed in the
>   Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.**
>
> **Please Contact your System Administrator.**

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Some additional details:

- I am using ClickOnce Deployment, and having the compilation configuration as 'x86' in 'Release' mode.
- The server on which I am deploying is Windows Server 2012 R2 with 64 Bit OS & x64 Bit Processor.

Comment: Got the same error. In my case, it was simply that Oracle was not installed. However, instead I installed Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio, which contains `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`, and changed my project to use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay...after implementing some Trial and Error methods, I found the solution to this problem in my case.

Please follow the below steps:

1. Change the Build Properties for your solution, keep platform setup as MIXED platform.
2. Deploy in Release Mode and re-publish the application.

It may work if you face the same problem as me.